# Call smart contract function by web3.js without response

Tags: javascript, web3js

I was watching the tutorial on Youtube and following the instruction:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=1350&v=msT3tpwnyv8

When I try to call the function with the js file below, it returned nothing on the console. Does anyone know what happened?

I am using, 
web3.js 1.0.0 beta. 52
infura to connect

```
var Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx')

const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3('https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/project_id')


const contractAddress = '0xd03696B53924972b9903eB17Ac5033928Be7D3Bc'
const contractABI = [{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"name","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_spender","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"approve","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"totalSupply","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_from","type":"address"},{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transferFrom","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"standard","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"symbol","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transfer","outputs":[{"name":"success","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"","type":"address"},{"name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"allowance","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"_from","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"_to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Transfer","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"_owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"_spender","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"_value","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Approval","type":"event"}]

var contract = new web3.eth.Contract(contractABI, contractAddress)


contract.methods.totalSupply().call((err, result)=> {
  console.log(result)
})
```

Comment: Hi @Eric, can you please try to explain your question more, in order to let more people understand it.

Comment: @Samer Abu Gahgah Thanks for your reply. Sure, I was trying to interact with a smart contract in Ethereum Ropsten net. I use web3.js to call the function which supposes to reply with the total number of tokens in that contract. I try to show the response in the console but nothing happened. No response and no error.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```js
contract.methods.totalSupply().call().then((result) => {console.log(result) });
```

It should return a BigNumber.